# How to handle SyncAdapter requests to a RESTful web service

Tags: android, web-services, rest, contacts, android-syncadapter

I am trying to build a contacts web service which could be synced with various RESTful clients.

Android has a Contacts provider and a SyncAdapter to do the job but i am actually trying to figure out how my web service should be like? I mean is there is a standard way to build a sync enabled services or it's going to use my CRUD operations? do CRUD operations has to be in a standard format?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a GAE example web application written in Python in the `SampleSyncAdapter` android app. It is included in a folder called `samplesyncadapter_server`